# Remove base-href from index.html on build time

Tags: flutter, github, github-pages, github-actions, flutter-web

I am trying to build a web app using GitHub action. On `jobs`  there is one step

```yaml
 - run: flutter build web --release --web-renderer html
```

This will generate `<base href="/">` inside `index.html`.

When I open the deployment page, it is completely blank.

After spending few days, I found some solutions like  removing `href` from `index.html` or providing `<base href="./">`. But  this is a manual process, on the other hand build and deployment is handled by `GitHub Action`.

Flutter added `base-href command in web` [#80519](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/80519/files/9694797bc557687765c7dea847f9c3369acacd09#diff-69a180b68dfcd8bebd68404980ba745dab7065c2aa36b0e24af7f1bd3347d019R97) but the `base-href` require `/` on start and end mentioned on [commands/build_web](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/a61c57add62f662ef5737434caf22fe06e335af1/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/commands/build_web.dart#L99-L101).

```dart
 if(!(stringArg('base-href').startsWith('/') && stringArg('base-href').endsWith('/')))
    {
       throwToolExit('base-href should start and end with /');
    }
```

How can I remove or pass `--base-href ./` to automate the process.

**build_deploy.yaml**

```yaml
name: Flutter Web
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build Web
    env:
      my_secret: ${{secrets.commit_secret}}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v1
        with:
          channel: 'stable'
      - run: flutter config --enable-web
      - run: flutter clean
      - run: flutter pub get
      # base ref need to remove or change manually(./)
      - run: flutter build web --release --web-renderer html --base-href /./
      - run: |
          cd build/web
          git init
          git config --global user.email mymail@gmail.com
          git config --global user.name yeasin50
          git status
          git remote add origin https://${{secrets.commit_secret}}@github.com/yeasin50/flavors_with_flutter.git
          git checkout -b gh-pages
          git add --all
          git commit -m "update"
          git push origin gh-pages -f
```

On test [repository](https://github.com/yeasin50/flavors_with_flutter)

Comment: is `sed` command not helpful?

Comment: i don't know about it, can you include more details/ref about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just found a solution, It can be changed from `web/index.html` on project root directory.

```html
<base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">
```

And on deployment git action it is necessary to provide repository name on base-href like `--base-href /repo_name/`

While the repository name is `flavors_with_flutter` it will be

```
- run: flutter build web --release --web-renderer html --base-href /flavors_with_flutter/
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit `public/index.html` to have

```
<base href="./"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay, but the issue was on git action